# How does the `grub-pc` postinstall script know which device to install to?

Tags: debian, apt, grub2, boot-loader

I recently moved my Debian Testing (bookworm) system to a new SSD. My boot device used to be `/dev/sdb` but is now `/dev/nvme0n1`. I've edited config files such as `crypttab` and `fstab` as necessary. Everything works, but just one little annoyance remains: Whenever the `grub-pc` package is updated, the postinstall script tries to run `install-grub` on `/dev/sdb`, generating a warning message that I have to dismiss.

How does this post-install script decide which device to install to, and how can I change it?

Comment: See what drive grub2 uses see this line   - grub-pc/install_devices:
`sudo debconf-show grub-pc` # for BIOS with grub-pc UEFI uses the mount of the ESP in fstab. to see similar drive info
`sudo lshw -C Disk -short `  This may also work: #to get grub2 to remember where to reinstall on major updates may update the install devices.
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc `

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, I wasn't aware of the whole debconf system, and indeed `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` prompted me to reselect the installation device. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what drive grub2 uses see this line for BIOS installs - grub-pc/install_devices:

```
sudo debconf-show grub-pc
```

Note that UEFI uses the mount of the ESP in fstab as it uses grub-efi-amd64, not grub-pc.

To see similar drive info:

```
sudo lshw -C Disk -short
```

This may also work to get grub2 to remember where to reinstall on major updates, it may update the install devices.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Old but still valid for BIOS info:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update/503446#503446