Moving /boot, how to update grub to find new location /boot/grub2/i386-pc/{core,boot}.img
Grub2 systems hard-code the location of stage2 files. This info is stored in the bootloader partition. I understand that grub-install will write this and more.
My question is how does grub2-install figure out where the /boot directory (it's own partition) happens to be. grub-mkconfig can figure this out, however, it does not appear that grub-install invokes grub-mkconfig.
I'd really like an in-depth explanation of how this is figured out.
Bottom line question is: "What is proper way to update the bootloader code in the mbr/bios-boot partition when location of /boot changes"?
Pointers to official documentation or wikis would be appreciated.

You are mixing up GRUB Legacy and GRUB2 terminology. The term "stage2" is for GRUB Legacy (i.e. versions 0.9x) only. But I think I understand what you mean.
When i386-pc version of GRUB is installed to the MBR and either the gap between the MBR and the first partition, or to the bios-boot partition, the /boot/grub2/i386-pc/{core,boot}.img files are only used by grub2-install, not by the actual boot process.
Since OS on i386-pc GRUB architecture has no reliable way to get information on how the BIOS last saw the disk ordering at boot time, grub-install basically has two options available on install time if configured to rely on BIOS disk support (as is the usual way):

if a /boot/grub[2]/device.map file has been provided, use the information in it to map the OS devices to GRUB device names (which will correspond directly to BIOS disk numbers)
if the device.map file is not available, make a wild guess that the current OS disk order is the same as the BIOS disk detection order. This guess may or may not be correct.

(Specifically, when running an installer or live media from USB, it is common to have the USB storage device be detected as the first "disk"; this can throw off the guess of grub-install, because once the installed OS boots on its own, the BIOS-level disk emulation for USB storage will no longer be there, as the BIOS won't be booting from USB media at that point.)
The GRUB boot code embedded in the actual MBR block contains two pieces of information written to it at grub-install time: the boot drive number and the LBA block number that GRUB should read next. In modern versions of GRUB, the drive number is usually encoded as 0xff, meaning "use the same disk BIOS used to read the MBR from".
When on a MBR-partitioned disk, the LBA block number will normally be 0x0000000000000001, pointing to the gap between the MBR and the first partition. On a MBR-partitioned disk, that is where the rest of the GRUB core image, essential modules, and the prefix string (which will point to the location of the /boot/grub directory) will be embedded to. On a GPT-partitioned disks, all of this will be written into the bios-boot partition instead, and the LBA block number embedded in the actual MBR boot code will be higher, as it will point to the beginning of the bios-boot partition.
The first block of the embedded code includes a blocklist that identifies which blocks to read next: when embedded to a MBR-partitioned disk, this will be a contiguous series of blocks starting from LBA block #2. The length of this series will mostly depend on the number and type of essential modules embedded along with the GRUB core image. Most of this embedded code will be LZMA compressed and then protected with Reed-Solomon error-correction codes, so modifying it will usually force you to essentially re-write the whole thing. Unfortunately the prefix string that identifies the location of the /boot/grub[2] directory will definitely be within the compressed part.
On modern systems, the gap between MBR and the start of the first partition is usually exactly 2047 blocks, to align the first partition to start at exactly 1 MiB into the disk. But older systems might have been partitioned with a version of fdisk that did not care about data alignment but instead tried to maintain DOS compatibility, positioning the beginning of partition at the beginning of a disk track (although the classic C/H/S disk geometry has long been just a fiction maintained by the disk firmware). In these cases, the gap between MBR and the start of the first partition can be much smaller. So, to maximize compatibility, the grub-install will need to embed the absolute minimum number of essential GRUB modules together with the core image, to minimize the size of the embedded code. For other relevant limits resulting from PC hardware and BIOS implementation, see GRUB documentation: i386-pc is considered a "heavily limited platform" in this regard.
On a simple RedHat/Debian installation on a MBR-based disk, with /boot as a separate partition that's the first partition on the disk, the typical set of embedded modules would be:

biosdisk.mod to use BIOS functions for disk access
part_msdos.mod to understand the MBR partition table
whatever module(s) are required to support the filesystem of the /boot partition

At minimum (if the /boot partition is initialized as an ext2 filesystem), the required GRUB modules for ext2 filesystem support will be ext2.mod and fshelp.mod. This is a practical configuration that will probably produce one of the smallest embedded code sizes achievable with modern GRUB on i386-pc architecture.
If the GRUB directory is named /grub on a separate /boot filesystem, and /boot is the first partition on the disk, the embedded prefix string will typically be (,msdos1)/grub. Note that the GRUB disk identifier is missing: this means "use the same disk the BIOS read the MBR from". The msdos1 indicates the first MBR-style partition on the disk, and /grub is simply the path of the /boot/grub directory starting from the root of the /boot filesystem.
And so, using only the code embedded in the MBR gap or the bios-boot partition, GRUB will have the capability to read normal.mod at (,msdos1)/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod using BIOS for disk support and the filesystem metadata to find the right blocks. After that, the configuration file will be read from (,msdos1)/grub/grub.cfg respectively.
It is also possible to embed e.g. ahci.mod and search_fs_uuid.mod together with the GRUB core image to give GRUB the capability to access AHCI SATA controllers directly and to identify the right partition/filesystem by UUID, but the ahci.mod is more than 3x the size of biosdisk.mod, which makes hitting the image size limits all the more likely.

What is proper way to update the bootloader code in the mbr/bios-boot partition when location of /boot changes"?

The only practical answer is "re-write the embedded bootloader code by running grub[2]-install again". When you do so, make sure you have the new /boot mounted as /boot, and if necessary, supply the /boot/grub/device.map file with contents appropriate to what the system configuration will be at the next boot.
On Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu and Mint, the package management system remembers the installation target device for the i386-pc version of GRUB. You can view this information with sudo debconf-show grub-pc, and update it with sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc.
RedHat doesn't seem to have a similar feature in their packaging.
RedHat and derivatives either don't upgrade the embedded boot code.
For comparison, on x86_64-efi GRUB architecture, there is usually no size restrictions to stop you from embedding all the available GRUB modules into the grubx64.efi file, resulting a single UEFI binary that can be signed for Secure Boot and will never need to load any executable code for extra functionality. In practice, this guarantees that as long as the system can read grubx64.efi, all the GRUB normal-mode command-line functionality will be available even if the /boot/grub[2] directory is completely destroyed.

Grub also saves drive info with BIOS installs and you can see it with sudo debconf-show grub-pc   Never used a separate /boot, so not sure what that output shows for separate /boot. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/745904/how-does-the-grub-pc-postinstall-script-know-which-device-to-install-to

@oldfred The information shown by debconf-show grub-pc is stored by the package manager's configuration system, not by GRUB itself. It is only used when the GRUB package is replaced by a newer one, and if that information seems to be incorrect at package update time, Debconf may pop up a question dialog about it. But that's a good point: it is best to pre-emptively keep that information up to date too, by running dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc or equivalent.
